# Is it possible to find a mail in store only by InternetMessageID without iterating through all folders

Tags: mapi

I'm looking for a way to find/open a mail in a mailbox by InternetMessageId with mapi.
I know that I could iterate through all folders but is there a smarter way?

With ews it's possible to do a mailbox wide search but I only can use mapi...

Thanks for your input!

Anne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a store wide search folder with the top IPM folder as the search root and the recursive bit set. But keep in mind that search folder is asynchronous - you will need to monitor its events to get notified when a match is found.

Or you can recursively iterate through all folders and call IMAPITable::FindRow. You can probably start with the most likely suspects (Inbox and the Sent Items folders).